# Designing a garden to work around buttresses

Tags: design, patio

I have moved into a new house with a fresh garden to decorate and this garden has a large wall with 3 buttresses at the rear, and I'm struggling to think how best to work around these...

[image: plan of garden]

I am wanting to get a shed to store my regular garden things and some wood - I was previously using a 6x4 foot at my old rental, so something similarly sized (same or larger) is what I am after, but I'm not sure the best way to go about starting a design.

Please, educate me.

---

Edit/Update:
Based on questions I have received in response to my post I will clarify a little further.

- I am based in the UK
- The green area indicates grass turf
- The black rectangle bottom-left is not garden and can be ignored
- The grey grid at the bottom is a small paved strip that my patio doors opens on to.

I should also point out that the sight line of my garden is mainly focussed on the right hand side, so I can clearly see the middle and right hand buttress-area, whereas the left is not immediately visible until you look for it - This may be the area I want my workshop/shed to go.

My motivation is simply to have a workshop/shed that I can do woodworking in, and potentially another, smaller shed for gardening tools etc.

We don't particularly care about foliage, but may have plans for some raised planters in the future.

Comment: Where in the world do you live? Is the area below the buttresses on your drawing grass or paving?

Comment: Why do you feel the buttresses are a problem? Do they cast shade? Do they dominate the garden? What is it about them that must be solved?

Comment: @Jurp I have updated with more info for you

Comment: Same for you @KateGregory

Answer (score 1):

Before starting any design, you should answer these questions (at least):

- What's the sun exposure in the area?
- What kind of soil does your garden have?
- Are you in an arid area, or do you get enough rain (20"-30", for example)?
- Do you know if drainage in the area is a problem (for example, if puddles form after a decent amount of rain and take awhile to disappear, then you have a drainage issue)?
- Do you plan on installing edging to separate the garden from the lawn? If so, whay kind of edging?
- What kind of mulch, if any, do you plan on using?
- Do you want to use part of the space for vegetables?
- Do you want mainly perennials? Annuals? Shrubs? A mix of these? If shrubs, are you looking for evergreen or deciduous?

After you've answered these questions, then it becomes, at first, a process of research (which your question here is part of) and implementation.

Here's a common design tip - when you're thinking about the shape(s) of your garden beds, you can use a hose to mark the border to see which shapes you like best. When you've found a shape you like, then (assuming there's a lawn), run your lawnmower (while off) along the bed as if you're mowing. This will make sure that you don't create a bed that's a hassle to mow around.

With the shed, you'll typically want to install a pad (especially if you have burrowing mammals in the area like woodchucks and ground squirrels - the pad discourages them from living under your shed). The pad also stabilizes the shed from the freeze-thaw cycle (if you live in a cold winter area). One of my sheds is on a simple 12" thick bed of compacted base gravel, which has worked really well. Once your shed is in place, you may want to pave the entrance with something like crushed stone (within edging) or a group of flagstones.

This answer just scratches the surface of garden design, so I also highly recommend that you find multiple sources for design tips (if you use online sources, don't stick with just a single source because it may give incorrect information - I've seen this frequently). IMO, you'd be best off with printed sources, as their methodologies have typically been vetted for accuracy.